PHP contact form. Strange output in "From:" field
I've got an issue, that is driving me crazy.
We have a PHP contact form on our websites. Recently it's been pointed out that when an email was received it was changing the suffix of the email address, to the domain the form was being sent from.
i.e. if the domain was doamin1.com but the email address from the form was johnsmith429@personalemaildomain.com the email would arrive as John Smith <johnsmith429@doamin1.com>
The code in the header line was
$header = "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";

I changed it to the following, hoping that it would then see the email address, and we're not overly bother about it not showing "$name" outside of the <$email> and we're still having some issues, but it's slightly better.
$header = "From: " . $email . "<". $email .">\r\n";

The from address now shows as johnsmith429" <personalemaildomain.comjohnsmith429@personalemaildomain.com>. Which is better, but not perfect.
I know it will be something little I'm missing, if someone can assist that would be perfect, thank you.
Thanks
Andy
Changed code from:
$header = "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";

to
$header = "From: " . $email . "<". $email .">\r\n";

now showing the correct email address in the second part between the "< >", but with the domain again at the front of the email address.

Have you considered using some library like PHPMailer where all these issues are already solved?

Most providers will not allow you to send emails with just any arbitrary From address. And even when they do, you should absolutely not set the address entered by the user in a form, as From address - because that will increase the likelihood of the mail considered to be spam on the receiving end, by a lot. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/1427878, section "Don't use a faux From: sender")

Use an address from your domain, that you are allowed to send emails for, as the From address. Put the address the user entered in the form, as the ReplyTo address.

Are there any quote characters in $name? They will need to be escaped.

You want a space between the name and the <>'d email:
$header = "From: " . $name . " <". $email .">\r\n";

Currently you're outputting:
From: A Smith<b@d.com>

or
From: b@d.com<b@d.com>

The correct format is:
From: A Smith <b@d.com>

As comment have said, email headers are finicky, so it may be easier to use a PHP Email Library like PHPMailer.
